# Rectangular lattice fit to noisey coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, coordinates, lattice

I have the following problem. Imaging you have a set of coordinates that are somewhat organized in a regular pattern, such as the one shown below. 
[image]

What i want to do is to automatically extract coordinates, such that they are ordered from left to right and top to bottom. In addition, the total number of coordinates should be as large as possible, but only include coordinates, such that the extracted coordinates are on a nearly rectangular grid (even if the coordinates have a different symmetry, e.g. hexagonal). I always want to extract coordinates that follow a rectangular unit cell structure.

For the example shown above, the largest number that contain such an orthorhombic set would be 8 x 8 coordinates (lets call this dimensions: m x n), as framed by the red rectangle.

The problem is that the given coordinates are noisy and distorted.
My approach was to generate an artificial lattice, and minimizing the difference to the given coordinates, taking into account some rotation, shift and simple distortion of the lattice. However, it turned out to be tricky to define a cost function that covers the complexity of the problem, i.e. minimizing the difference between the given coordinates and the fitted lattice, but also maximizing the grid components m x n.

If anyone has a smart idea how to tackle this problem, maybe also with machine learning algorithms, i would be very thankful.

Here is the code that i have used so far:
A function to generate the artificial lattice with m x n coordinates that are spaced by a and b in the "n" and "m" directions. The angle theta allows for a rotation of the lattice.

```
def lattice(m, n, a, b, theta):
    coords = []
    for j in range(m):
        for i in range(n):
            coords.append([np.sin(theta)*a*i + np.cos(theta)*b*j, np.cos(theta)*a*i - np.sin(theta)*b*j])
    return np.array(coords)
```

I used the following function to measure the mean minimal distance between points, which is a good starting point for fitting:

```
def mean_min_distance(coords):
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    cd = distance.cdist(coords, coords)
    cd_1 = np.where(cd == 0, np.nan, cd)
    return np.mean(np.nanmin(cd_1, axis=1))
```

The following function provides all possible combinations of m x n that theoretically fit into the lengths of the coordinates, whose arrangement is assumed to be unknown. The ability to limit this to minimal and maximal values is included already:

```
def get_all_mxn(l, min_m=2, min_n=2, max_m=None, max_n=None):
    poss = []
    if max_m is None:
        max_m = l + 1
    if max_n is None:
        max_n = l +1
    for i in range(min_m, max_m):
        for j in range(min_n, max_n):
            if i * j <= l:
                poss.append([i, j])
    return np.array(poss)
```

The definition of the costfunction i used (for one particular set of m x n). So i first wanted to get a good fit for a certain m x n arrangement.

```
def cost(x0):
    a, b, theta, shift_a, shift_b, dd1 = x0
    # generate lattice
    l = lattice(m, n, a, b, theta) 
    # distort lattice by affine transformation
    distortion_matr = np.array([[1, dd1], [0, 1]]) 
    l = np.dot(distortion_matr, l.T).T
    # shift lattice 
    l = l + np.array((shift_b, shift_a))

    # Some padding to make the lists the same length
    len_diff = coords.shape[0] - l.shape[0]
    l = np.append(l, (1e3, 1e3)*len_diff).reshape((l.shape[0] + len_diff, 2))

    # calculate all distances between all points
    cd = distance.cdist(coords, l)
    minimum distance between each artificial lattice point and all coords
    cd_min = np.min(cd[:, :coords.shape[0] - len_diff], axis=0)

    # returns root mean square difference of all minimal distances
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(cd_min) ** 2) )
```

I then run the minimization:

```
md = mean_min_distance(coords) 
# initial guess
x0 = np.array((md, md, np.deg2rad(-3.), 3, 1, 0.12))
res = minimize(cost, x0)
```

However, the results are extremely dependend on the initial parameter x0 and i have not even included a fitting of m and n.

Comment: it would better if you shared whatever code you have already tried as this often allows people to see your probem clearly

Comment: Thank you. i have added the code.